# Removal of foreign letters while keeping english letters with accents in python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

Is there any way to remove foreign letters but keep english letters with accents in python?

e.g. I would want Pic d’Ós to be converted to Pic d'Os but not have 马萨纳 converted to Ma Sa Na - ideally I would want it converted to a blank string.

I have used unidecode but unidecode converts foreign letters to ascii as well.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to find which substrings have the character class `Letter` or `Number` but not `Latin`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. I do want to accept the Latin  character class because I want to include letters with accents. So I can now use a regex that only accepts letters, numbers and latin characters instead of using unidecode - I didn't know there was a latin character class so that helped a lot. If you wish, you can add an answer to this question stating that I should  use regex including letter, numbers and latin character class and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern regular-expression engines support a character class `Latin` or `isLatin`, which will match accented or unaccented Latin letters.

A regular expression matching only what you want would be a little more complicated. You **do not** want to simply match `Letter` or `Number`, as those will match letters and numbers from other scripts.  Neither do you want to include or exclude all combining accents: you want small Latin letter a + combining acute accent to show up as á, but an accented Greek letter not to.  So, you would want to match something like `(\p{Latin}\p{Mark}*)|\p{Punctuation}|\p{Separator}`.